# locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region) bug?

Tags: swift, location, locationmanager

I have a strange problem, and I can't work it out for the life of me.

I am creating an app that monitors regions in the background, but it seems to intermittently not monitor some regions
(I have set location permission to always, and have enabled background location capabilities).

The regions that it does monitor work fine, so it appears to be something to do with `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)`

the app is quite straight forward, and each time a region is added or edited, it:

1. stops monitoring all regions
2. then, if there are less than 20 regions, start monitoring all regions
3. otherwise, calculate closest 20 and start monitoring them

here is the code

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()



if(regionsArray.count <= 20{

    //monitor all regions
    monitorAllRegions()

}else{

    //calculate closest 20 regions, and monitor them

    //do some stuff here.....
}


func monitorAllRegions(){

    //stop monitoring all regions
    stopMonitoringAllRegions()

    //start monitoring all regions in array
    for region in regionsArray{
        locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region)
    }

    //check all regions are monitored
    print(regionsArray.count)
    print(locationManager.monitoredRegions.count)

}


func stopMonitoringAllRegions() {

    //stop monitoring all monitored regions
    for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
        locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
    }

}
```

once all regions are monitored, it then prints the total number of regions in the array, along with the total number of monitored regions, just to make sure they were all added.
the strange thing is, about 50% of the time, the monitored region count is less than the region array count, so it's not monitoring 1 or more regions??

first of all I assumed there was a problem with one or more of the regions, but it's not always the same regions that are missed (I've checked the regions in the array against the monitored regions).

also, it doesn't always happen, for example:

I open region 1, make no changes, then save... the counts are equal

I then open region 1 again, make no changes and save... the monitored count is now less than the array count?

another weird thing is, if I set a breakpoint on locationManager.startMonitoring(for: region), it works absolutely fine, as if slowing the code down makes it work properly somehow?
but as soon as I disable the BP and let the code just run, it starts not monitored locations again

is this a bug, or is there something silly that I'm missing?
I'm pretty new to swift coding, and it's my first attempt at region monitoring, so I'm a bit stumped

any help would be greatly appreciated